# EXCEL filter column A that has multiple B value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

im not an expert in excel, but right now i have an excel with more than 80k data
this data contains provinces cities districts and zipcode, i want to filter and copies all districts that has more than one zipcode, is this posible?

e.g:

```
District Zipcode 
LOVE     10000
LOVE     10000
LOVE     10000
LOVE     10000
HATE     12000
HATE     12000
HATE     12000
HATE     12030
HATE     12031
```

from above example i wanna get HATE district, can someone help me ? what formula do i need? thanks a lot

Comment: Look on here for examples of vlookup() or index() with match().

Comment: One way is COUNTIF, other is simple Pivot table where you count ZipCodes

Comment: Please include whatever formula it is you tried and didn't work for debugging purposes.

Comment: You should try using `POWER QUERY` for `80K` rows of data I won't be using Excel Formulas unless you are an `O365` User, Still most experts I found shall go for either `VBA` or `POWER QUERY`.  Also kindly note & follow what @JvdV Sir wants to say.